# Como implementar um "listener" em javascript para visualização da tela?

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-eventos, listener, event-listener

Eu preciso implementar uma alteração no meu código para que ao mudar de DIV, ou seja, deixar de visualizar a página, o som que está sendo executado pare automaticamente, conforme já acontece com os vídeos do `Facebook/Instagram` nas plataformas web. Eu fiz o seguinte código:

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="../media_a/song3.mp3" preload="auto">
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var isPlaying = false;

function togglePlay() {
if (isPlaying) {
myAudio.pause()
} else {
myAudio.play();
}
}; 
myAudio.onplaying = function() {
isPlaying = true;
};
myAudio.onpause = function() {
myAudio.currentTime = 0;
isPlaying = false;
};
</script>
```

O botão ON/OFF está 100% funcional, mas quando eu chamo outra DIV, num sistema de página única, o áudio deve parar de ser executado, porém ele continua. Sendo que cada DIV tem uma audiodescrição diferente, como implemento um "listener" para que ao deixar de visualizar aquela DIV o som pare automaticamente?

Comment: Como você está carregando essa outra página? Você poderia adicionar o código para pausar o áudio, dentro dessa função.

Comment: Quando você diz "mudar de página" seria mudar de aba? Esse ponto não ficou claro.

Comment: Tenho um menu que através de um script chama as DIVs.

Comment: @Elanio é o mesmo que coloquei na pergunta. Ele é do tipo ON/OFF reiniciando o áudio, só que ao chamar outra DIV ele continua tocando, e como cada DIV tem seu próprio áudio, complica porque o áudio embola todo. misturando os sons.